# unable to increase the client_max_body_size using the .ebextensions method

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-config

I tried to increase the default client_max_body_size to 50M using the .ebextension folder method and when i upload my .zip project folder to Elastic Beanstalk the conf file is not deploying.

My **proxy.config** file inside **.ebextensions** folder

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
        content: |
           client_max_body_size 20M;
```

This didn't working for me.
My AMI: **Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.0.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This caught me out too on my first build using Node 12 on AL2.

In the end the solution was to create the following file in my project:

/.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf

And in there you just need the single line:

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

It worked for me, I hope it works for you too.

The documentation on configuring the Amazon Linux 2 platform:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

(See Reverse Proxy Configuration)

Comment: Thanks @mark.infinity, after a lot of research and multiple attempts and cross checking the log files i too reached to this solution. I have achieved it and you answered the same solution and i am making it as correct answer. We may also need to add `service nginx reload` as the config command

Comment: Hi Jijo, glad you got it sorted, and thank you for marking mine as the answer even though you arrived at the same conclusion independently. Cheers M